# Filter by boolean==false in MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my .NET Core application I have model with props like

```cs
{   
  public ObjectId Id  { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and trying to make a query:

```cs
var filter = Collection.Find(x => !x.IsDeleted);
```

I have got query filter document (`filter.ToString()`) like this:

```js
{ "IsDeleted": { $ne: true } }
```

**Is there any way to get filter like this instead?**

```js
{ "IsDeleted": false }
```

Cause as soon `bool` is not nullable and not ignored it has to be `false`.
Of course I can write it like this and it works, but it's kinda strange:

```cs
Collection.Find(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
```

I tried `[BsonRequired]` and `[BsonDefaultValue(false)]` attributes on `IsDeleted` but no luck.

*PS. I need this cause it fails sorting by index in MongoDB. For example if we have compound index `{IsDeleted: 1, Name: 1}` then `collection.find({ IsDeleted: false }).sort({ Name: 1 })` will sort by index, but `collection.find({ IsDeleted: { $ne: true } }).sort({ Name: 1 })` will sort in memory (it's bad)*

Answer (score 1):

To fix sorting issue, use: `.Sort({IsDeleted:1, Name:1})`